# What can one assume about $T^*$ when showing that $T$ is normal?

Tags: operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Consider a continuous and linear operator $T$ such that
$$ T : l^2 \to l^2 $$ where $(a_n) \mapsto (\alpha_n a_n)$

Moreover $(\alpha_n)$ is a sequence of complex numbers that converges to zero.

Now, it must be shown that $T$ is normal, that is $TT^* = T^*T$ but I'm not sure how to take $T^*$ as no information was given.

Any insight on how to start would be appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Here are some thoughts:

Let $(a_n), (b_n)\in l^2$. Their inner product is given by:
$$
\langle (a_n), (b_n) \rangle = a_1\bar{b_1} + a_2\bar{b_2} + \cdots
$$
Hence, 
$$
\langle T(a_n), (b_n) \rangle = \alpha_1a_1\bar{b_1} + \alpha_2a_2\bar{b_2} + \cdots
$$
The defining property of $T^*$ is that it satisfies:
$$
\langle T(a_n), (b_n) \rangle = \langle (a_n), T^*(b_n) \rangle
$$
So if $T^*(b_n) = (b^*_n)$, we know that 
\begin{align*}
\langle T(a_n), (b_n) \rangle &= \langle (a_n), T^*(b_n) \rangle \\
\alpha_1a_1\bar{b_1} + \alpha_2a_2\bar{b_2} + \cdots &= a_1\bar{b^*_1} + a_2\bar{b^*_2} + \cdots 
\end{align*} 
From this, it seems like we can infer that $\bar{b^*_n} = \alpha_n\bar{b_n}$; or, in other words, 
$$
T^*(b_n) = (\bar{\alpha_n}b_n)
$$ 
That should give you a good start. In short, when we don't know anything else about $T^*$, we can use the fact that we know $T^*$ satisfies
$$
\langle Tx, y \rangle = \langle x, T^*y \rangle
$$
for all $x,y$ to make progress.